# How to get outside login data (session) in WordPress?

Tags: session

i want to use codeignider login form session in wp login form

```
public function check_login()
{     

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        redirect('/');
    }
    //Set Page Title
    $data['title'] = "Check Login"; 

     $username = $this->input->post('username');
     $email = $this->input->post('username');
     $password = $this->input->post('password');        
     $password = hash('sha1',$password);
    echo (int)$is_admin = $this->loginmodel->user_login($username, $email, $password);
       $_SESSION['sumit']['puri']=$this->session->userdata('id');
    // print_r($is_admin);
    //
}
```

Comment: So you have codeignider (CI) and wordpress (WP), and you want the CI to generate the form, and WP to check the authentication?

Comment: yes,please help me, in my website all task perform by ci but only blog are integreted by wordpress.for the login purpose of the user which used the blog part will only login through the ci but they will also permission use the blog like comment or reply after logging the ci login

Comment: http://takethisjoborshoveit.com/login this is ci login                                                                   http://takethisjoborshoveit.com/blog/?p=96&user_id=    wordpress

Answer (score 1):

To use Wordpress as Authenticator, you can use the function [wp_signon()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon).
So take the post-data from the codeignider and send it to `wp_signon()`

Comment: thanx for helping me but i am new to wordpress and codeignider  may you explain in detail plz.........

Comment: check the exemple on the linked page, and change the row to look like   
`$creds['user_login'] = $this->input->post('username');`

Comment: great it working but when i login through ci why i need login again for comment in wordpress http://takethisjoborshoveit.com/blog/?p=96&user_id= You must be logged in to post a comment.

Comment: if user are register in both table like tbl_user for ci and wp_users for wordpress. if login through ci,it means they have permission for access entire blog like comment

Comment: if you need code of ci tell me plz

Comment: plz give me some hint about how login through in ci and user will acess the blog for give comments

Comment: check the exemple on the linked page, and change the row to look like $creds['user_login'] = $this->input->post('username'); it will work but now i not login in wordpress error:username field empty